# What does the & operator do in PyTorch and why does it change the shape?

Tags: pytorch

I have code that contains `x` and `y`, both of the type `torch.autograd.variable.Variable`. Their shape is

```
torch.Size([30, 1, 9])
torch.Size([1, 9, 9])
```

What I don't understand is, why the following results in a different size/shape

```
z = x & y
print(z.shape)
```

which outputs

```
torch.Size([30, 9, 9])
```

**Why is the shape of `z` 30*9*9, after `x & y`? The shape of `x` is 30*1*9, and the shape of `y` is 1*9*9, what does `&` do in `x & y`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the `&` operator, but with how broadcasting works in Python. To quote [Eric Wieser's excellent documentation on broadcasting](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc) in NumPy:

> In order to broadcast, the size of the trailing axes for both arrays in an operation must either be the same size or one of them must be one.

See the following image from the quoted page as an example:

[image: Broadcasting of tensors of different shape.]

This translates to your problem as follows:

- `a` has the shape 30 x 1 x 9
- `b` has the shape  1 x 9 x 9

Therefore the result is created like this:

- `result1` is `a1`, because `a1 > b1`
- `result2` is `b2`, because `a2 < b2`
- `result3` is both `a3` and `b3`, because `a3 = b3`

Therefore `result` has the shape 30 x 9 x 9.

Please also note that the `&` operator implements [logical conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction) on a binary encoding of the tensors' items.